# White spaces throwing off HTML form validation

Tags: php

When using: `if (empty($_POST['Username'])){ .. }` The user can input a number of whitespaces so therefore the post is technically not empty, so it continues the insert into my database. I want the fields to contain text.. Is there a way to perform this?

Comment: **1)** use `trim()`, **2)** In the HTML part use the attribute `required` **3)** HTML5 even supports the attribute `pattern` to validate the input with regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function.

```
if (empty(trim($_POST['Username']))){ .. }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about;

```
if (empty($_POST['Username']) || trim($_POST['Username'] == ""){
```

This will check if the POST key value is empty, but if it is not.. It will remove all whitespaces and then check if it's equal to nothing