# Can't use function return value in write context?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
public function __construct($Directory = null) 
{
    if ($Directory === null) {
        trigger_error("Directory Must Be Set!", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    if (isset($Directory)) {
        if (!empty(trim($Directory))) { //Error Line
            echo "test"; 
        }
    }
}
```

(The echo is for my debugging purposes.)

I get returned with the fatal error:

> Can't use function return value in write context

According to PHP storm this returns:

> Variable Expected

But using the code directly from this question:

[White spaces throwing off HTML form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761323/white-spaces-throwing-off-html-form-validation)

This is the correct syntax, as i've used it in the past... But, in this situation this is throwing an error. Why is this?

Comment: on the first result in google i found that you can't pass a function return value to `empty`, must be a variable

Answer (score 113, accepted):

From the PHP docs on the `empty` function:

> Note:
>   Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

So you will have to split that line into something like the following:

```
$trimDir = trim($Directory);
if(!empty($trimDir))
```