# Can't use function return value in write context Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm getting the **Can't use function return value in write context** error on line 430 in my code, but I can't understand why I'm getting this error..

Strange thing is, I only get this error on the server (PHP 5.3) and not on my localhost (PHP 5.5.10)

```
return  Redirect::route('account-activate-user', (empty(Input::get('code'))) ? '{code}' : e(Input::get('code')))
        ->with('global', 'De activatie-code is niet geldig.');
```

Does anyone have the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you're using `empty()` with the return value of a function (`Input::get()`), when it only accepts a variable. Considering how `Input::get()` works, i.e. you can pass a 2nd parameter as a **default** value when the input isn't set, you can skip the `empty()` check altogether and just use:

```
return  Redirect::route('account-activate-user', Input::get('code', '{code}'))
        ->with('global', 'De activatie-code is niet geldig.');
```

or, closer to your code:

```
return  Redirect::route('account-activate-user', (Input::has('code') ? '{code}' : e(Input::get('code')))
        ->with('global', 'De activatie-code is niet geldig.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior to PHP5.5 the function `empty()` cannot accept a return value.

This means that `Input::get('code')` returns a value, and this value cannot be passed to an `empty()` function.

Although not the best solution you could quickly fix this way:

```
$inputCode = Input::get('code');

return  Redirect::route('account-activate-user', (empty($inputCode)) ? '{code}' : e($inputCode))
->with('global', 'De activatie-code is niet geldig.');
```

However here you can find duplicates:

[Can't use function return value in write context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139264/cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and updating PHP version to 5.5.x fixed it for me.